# Angular 7 and Reactive form Array is returning an error of Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, angular-material-6, formarray

I am getting data from server to the component.

This data contains something called `Family Relation` having multiple values, that can be selected from the drop down list to change the original family relation value.

What I want is to create an array of form control inputs using Reactive Forms, to display drop down list at each row of the angular material table data source.

[Here is a working stackblitz that give you a great idea of the problem.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kz1fnj)

Here is the scripts. I replaced the server data with 2 array examples (`familyRelationArray` and `data`):

The getFamilyRelation() method gets the type of relations and display them. At the stackblitz, you can see that the drop down list menu is at the bottom (which is not a problem on my computer):

```
getFamilyRelation() {

    //This function gets data from server, but for testing purposes, I filled an array:
    this.familyRelationArray = [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: 'Father'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: 'Mother'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: 'Sister'
      }
    ]
  }
```

The `getData()` method is to get original data and display them in material table by applying the result to `dataSource` having the type of `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();`:

```
getData() {
    //For testing purposes, I filled an array of data instead of getting data from servers
    this.data = [
      {
        name: 'xyz', head_hh: 'Yes', fr: 'Parent', frid: 2, ms: 'Married', sts: 'Active', age: '61', iid: 123
      },
      {
        name: 'yxz', head_hh: 'No', fr: 'Child', frid: 3, ms: 'Single', sts: 'Active', age: '25', iid: 221
      },
    ]
    this.showEmpty = false;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((this.data));
    this.resultsLength = this.data.length;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;


  }
```

Here is the FormArray method, which create the drop list at each row:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      test: this.createArray()
    })
  }

createArray(): FormArray {
    return new FormArray(this.dataSource.data.map(item => new FormGroup({
      fr: new FormControl(item.frid)
    })));
  }
```

The html script, contain the created form array using `formArrayName="test"` and `formGroupName="i"` where `i` is the index of the created drop list:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-content>
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort formArrayName="test">

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <b>{{element.name}}</b> </td>

          </ng-container>


          <ng-container matColumnDef="head_hh">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Head Of HH </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.head_hh}} </td>
          </ng-container>


          <ng-container matColumnDef="fr" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Family Rel. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
              <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Drop List</mat-label>
                    <mat-select id="family_relation" formControlName="fr" placeholder="Drop List">                 
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="frid">
                        {{familyRelation.type}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                </div>
                  <i>Original Value: {{element.fr}}</i>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="ms">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Marital Sts. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ms}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sts}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Age </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSizeOptions]="[15, 25, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

The error is that I can't set the value of each drop list to be equal to the `orignal value` displayed under each drop down list, and an error at the console saying:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'test

I tried [the solutions of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679637/angular-2-form-cannot-find-control-with-path) on stack but nothing worked.

Comment: instead of constructor, can you add it in oninit.